# Your browser sent an invalid or no HTTP referer error Lighttpd when trying to shorten url and change document-root

Tags: reverse-proxy, lighttpd

Having a site setup using lighttpd, it's first url was:

`http://localhost/vichan/recent.html`

I then wanted to put it on a different port to then tunnel it later and shorten the url to make it looks more pretty by putting this in my `lighttpd.conf`:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":4447" {
        server.document-root = "/var/www/html/vichan/"
        index-files.names = ("recent.html")
}
```

noticed that `.css` and `.js` werent able to be found, due to the config turning `localhost:4447/vichan/style.css` to `localhost:4447/vichan/vichan/style.css`, I added a new statement to the rule to compensate for it:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":4447" {
        server.document-root = "/var/www/html/vichan/"
        index-files.names = ("recent.html")

        $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/vichan/"{
                server.document-root = "/var/www/html/"
        }
}
```

but then when I tried to make a request to a `.php` file, it returned me with `Your browser sent an invalid or no HTTP referer.`

And I couldn't understand how or why it happens, is there anything that's missing?